# Cannot filter data Locally in DevExpress

Tags: javascript, json, devexpress

I got the result from database as

```
var dataSource = [{ "ID": 1, "ProductName": "P1", "InYear": 2015, "Revenue": 500 },
   { "ID": 2, "ProductName": "P2", "InYear": 2015, "Revenue": 700 },
   { "ID": 3, "ProductName": "P3", "InYear": 2015, "Revenue": 600 },
   { "ID": 4, "ProductName": "P1", "InYear": 2016, "Revenue": 800 },
   { "ID": 5, "ProductName": "P2", "InYear": 2016, "Revenue": 900 },
   { "ID": 6, "ProductName": "P3", "InYear": 2016, "Revenue": 400 }]
```

I need to filter the data. So I use filter options as follows

```
 var newDataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
                     dataSource: dataSource,
                    filter: [
                        ["InYear", ">=", startFromYear],
                     "&&",
                        ["InYear", "<=", endWithYear]
                    ],

                });
```

where startFromYear=2014 and endWithYear=2016.

I have used

```
  newDataSource.load();
  alert('length'+newDataSource.items.length);
 $('#chartContainer').dxChart('instance').option('dataSource', newDataSource);
```

I'm getting result as length = 0 after filtration. And I'm not getting the result. May I know what's the mistake have I committed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
"&&",
```

to

```
"and",
```

according to the specification of [Group Filter Operations](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer/?version=15_2#Data_Layer_Data_Layer_Reading_Data_Filtering_Group_Filter_Operations), it must be `"and"` or `"or"`.